# Running VBA macros in documents created using template

Tags: vba, templates, docx

I have macro-enabled templete (.dotm) wich has number of macros generally connected with adding and deleting parts of document using custom building blocks stored in the template.

When I execute macros at the actual template file everything works smooth.

But when I try to execute them in documents created using this template macros stop working after one run of the particular function (attached to checkbox).

Additionally in some cases checkboxes turn into pictures when saving documents as .docx files.

What could be wrong with this document?

Comment: Some code, specifically where it stops working, would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by recreating problem checkbox.