# VBA macros stop working after delete commandbutton only in docm from dotm

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I have a problem very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689001/running-vba-macros-in-documents-created-using-template)

However the answer there is not very clear, and I tried recreating the commandbutton in question, and it did not work.

Basically I have various sections within the template and for each section I have two buttons

1. **[Add sub-section]** - (CommandButton1, CommandButton11, CommandButton111)
2. **[Done]** - (CommandButton2, CommandButton21, CommandButton211)

Everything works fine in the template.

But if I create a new doc by either double clicking on the dotm or right clicking->new and then try using the buttons, they all run well, until I try one of the [Done] buttons. At the first attempt it works, post which no code works what so ever. Here's the code

```
        Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
         Dim objTemplate As Template
         Dim objBB As BuildingBlock

         ' Set the template to store the building block
         Set objTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate

         ' Access the building block through the type and category
         Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeCustom5) _
         .Categories("General").BuildingBlocks("Experience")

         ' Insert the building block into the document replacing any selected text.
         Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
         objBB.Insert Selection.Range
        End Sub

        Private Sub CommandButton11_Click()
         Dim objTemplate As Template
         Dim objBB As BuildingBlock

         ' Set the template to store the building block
         Set objTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate

         ' Access the building block through the type and category
         Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeCustom5) _
         .Categories("General").BuildingBlocks("Experience")

         ' Insert the building block into the document replacing any selected text.
         Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
         objBB.Insert Selection.Range
        End Sub

        Private Sub CommandButton111_Click()
            Dim objTemplate As Template
         Dim objBB As BuildingBlock

         ' Set the template to store the building block
         Set objTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate

         ' Access the building block through the type and category
         Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeCustom5) _
         .Categories("General").BuildingBlocks("Education")

         ' Insert the building block into the document replacing any selected text.
         Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
         objBB.Insert Selection.Range
        End Sub

        Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

           On Error Resume Next
            Err.Clear

            Dim i As Integer
            i = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
            Do While (i > 0)
                If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).OLEFormat.ClassType = "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then

                    If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).OLEFormat.Object.Name = "CommandButton1" _
                    Or ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).OLEFormat.Object.Name = "CommandButton2" Then

                        If Err.Number = 0 Then
                            ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).Delete
                        End If
                        Err.Clear

                    End If

                End If
                i = i - 1
            Loop

        End Sub

        Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
            On Error Resume Next
            Err.Clear

            Dim i As Integer
            i = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
            Do While (i > 0)
                If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).OLEFormat.ClassType = "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then

                    If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).OLEFormat.Object.Name = "CommandButton11" _
                    Or ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).OLEFormat.Object.Name = "CommandButton21" Then

                        If Err.Number = 0 Then
                            ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).Delete
                        End If
                        Err.Clear

                    End If

                End If
                i = i - 1
            Loop
        End Sub

        Private Sub CommandButton211_Click()
            On Error Resume Next
            Err.Clear

            Dim i As Integer
            i = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
            Do While (i > 0)
                If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).OLEFormat.ClassType = "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then

                    If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).OLEFormat.Object.Name = "CommandButton111" _
                    Or ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).OLEFormat.Object.Name = "CommandButton211" Then

                        If Err.Number = 0 Then
                            ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).Delete
                        End If
                        Err.Clear

                    End If

                End If
                i = i - 1
            Loop
```

I'm new to VBA and built this by putting together various snippets from various sources ( I know it may not be all that neat, but had to start somewhere). The [Done] code (commandbutton2,21,211) came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902582/trouble-deleting-commandbuttons-by-name-in-vba-word-10) I had asked earlier, just to give you some context.

In the editor I have three projects

1. **Normal**

   - Microsoft Word Objects

     - ThisDocument - [Empty]
2. **Document1**

   - Microsoft Word Objects

     - ThisDocument - [Empty]
   - References

     - Reference to Template Project
3. **Template**

   - Microsoft Word Objects

     - ThisDocument - [Got all the code]

I tried manually copying all of the code in "template" project into the "document1" project and then saving it as a docm. This fixed the problem, however I can't settle for this as [Add sub-section] basically adds a building block stored in the original template(which wont be available if I were to mail the docm to someone).

I'm open to any solution as long as at the end of it I have a file that can be mailed to someone and they could add sections at the click of a button

Comment: "no code works whatsoever" looks like what exactly?  If you place a break in the button code does it get hit when you click the button?  Try commenting out the `On Error Resume Next` and see what (if any) error you get.

Comment: well I have a few other "inlineshapes" in the form of horizontal lines in the template. If i comment out the `On Error Resume Next` I get a "this member cannot be accessed on a horizontal line" error.

Answer (score 0):

When using `On Error Resume Next` to manage an anticipated problem it's best to limit its scope as much as possible, or you run the risk of masking other errors in your code.

For example, you can remove it from your posted code by creating an "IsButton()" function something like this:

```
Function Isbutton(s) As Boolean
    Dim f As String
    On Error Resume Next
    f = s.OLEFormat.ClassType
    On Error GoTo 0
    Isbutton = (f = "Forms.CommandButton.1")
End Function
```

Factoring out the repeated code it reduces to something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   InsertSection
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton11_Click()
   InsertSection
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton111_Click()
   InsertSection
End Sub


Sub InsertSection()
    Dim objTemplate As Template
    Dim objBB As BuildingBlock

    Set objTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate
    Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeCustom5) _
    .Categories("General").BuildingBlocks("Experience")

    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    objBB.Insert Selection.Range
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    DeleteButtons "CommandButton1", "CommandButton2"
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    DeleteButtons "CommandButton11", "CommandButton21"
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton211_Click()
    DeleteButtons "CommandButton111", "CommandButton211"
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteButtons(Name1 As String, Name2 As String)

    Dim i As Integer, s As InlineShape, nm As String
    i = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count

    Do While (i > 0)
        Set s = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i)
        If Isbutton(s) Then
            nm = s.OLEFormat.Object.Name
            Debug.Print i, nm '<<<EDIT
            If nm = Name1 Or nm = Name2 Then s.Delete
        End If
        i = i - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for simplifying my code, much easier to maintain, but the problem still persists. Basically it works as expected in the dotm, but if a create a new docm, it breaks on the click of the delete buttons

Comment: No error messages, at the first click of any delete button it works as expected, post which all buttons do nothing

Comment: Basically I can use the [add section] buttons as many times as I want as long as i don't use the [done] button. If I click any of the [Done] buttons, it would work only the first time after which no button would work

Comment: See my edit above for a Debug line - maybe your button names aren't what you expect?  Anyway, bit late for me here, so have to sign off for now.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but there's no change in behavior. Just thinking out loud, based on the behavior it seems like the reference to the "template project" breaks on the delete code.(As the same code works well in the template but breaks only when a new doc is created) I might be wrong but just putting the thought forward.

Comment: If something was broken you'd expect to see an error - if what you're seeing is just nothing happening then that seems to point to something else.  Try stepping though the code and debugging the process.