# Deleting specific ActiveX Objects in MS Word using VBA without affecting other buttons

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to delete two specific objects, an combobox named `ComboBox1` and a button named `btnselect`. 
The code would run when clicking the `btnselect`.

The code that I've written is this one:

```
Dim obj1 As Object
For Each obj1 In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If obj1.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "ComboBox1" Then
        obj1.Delete
    End If
Next obj1
Dim obj2 As Object
For Each obj2 In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If obj2.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "btnselect" Then
        obj2.Delete
    End If
    Next obj2
```

Also, I have tried the following code:

```
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Delete 
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Delete
```

Both the code work and the specified ActiveX objects are deleted. 
However, after running this code, the other buttons that have vba code attached to them would not work. 
To be more specific, the problem occurs only when a create new document based on the template. If I run the buttons directly from the template, there is no problem. Without these codes, the buttons work as intended in a new document based on the template.
Could you help me find a way to delete these two objects without interfering with the other objects?

**LATER EDIT**: I narrowed the code down as much as I could so that the problem still persists.

```
Private Sub btnselect_Click()
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Delete
End Sub
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
MsgBox "Working"
End Sub
Private Sub btnPrint_Click()
MsgBox "Working"
End Sub
```

The template has three buttons, `btnselect`, `btnSubmit` and `btnPrint` and it contains the above-mentioned VBA code.
I want to delete the `btnselect` in a new document that's based on the template.

If I create a new document based on the template and click the btnselect, the button gets deleted, but then the other two buttons aren't working anymore.

If I open the template and click the btnselect, the button gets deleted and the other two buttons are working (they are displaying the messages).

Comment: Do they depend on these buttons? By the way, you only need to loop once. `If obj1.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "ComboBox1" Or obj1.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "btnselect" Then` that would delete both buttons in a single loop.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. No, they do not depend. They have some formatting code only (Find and replace) and print actions. I've put both objects in the same loop, as you suggested, to simplify the code. I do not know what's causing this problem, that's why I am trying to find an alternative.

Comment: Being the first two objects, I have tried using this code ```ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Delete
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Delete```. They get deleted, but this also break my other buttons

Comment: To be more specific, the rest of the buttons work only if I open the template, not a new document based on the template.

Comment: I imagine part of the problem comes from deleting the object attached to the code... Please show us more context - the entire `Sub` and where that is located (module and file (you say the template attached to the document?))

Comment: @CindyMeister, I simplified the sub as much as I could. ```Private Sub btnselect_Click()
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Delete
End Sub
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
MsgBox "Working"
End Sub
Private Sub btnPrint_Click()
MsgBox "Working"
End Sub
``` This is a vba in a .dotm. In the template, there are three buttons. If I open a new document based on the template, the vba for the `btnSubmit` and `btnPrint` don't work anymore after I click `btnselect`.

Comment: Please use the [edit] llink below the question to add additional information to the question, itself. Code in a comment is unusable... You need to provide *exact steps* on how to reproduce what's the problem situation.

Comment: @Asger, check my previous comment. Thanks!

Comment: I can reproduce it :) By deleting the first button, the other ones loose their connection to their VBA-code within the template. Unfortuantely I have no solution actually. (And yes: Please put that reduced button code into your question).

Comment: @CindyMeister, please check my edited question, in the LATER EDIT section. Thank you both for the input.

Comment: Same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28930605/10908769), but without helpful answer. So I suggest to somewhat "hide" the button instead of deleting it. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the other buttons working, don't delete any button. If you delete it, all other buttons from your `ActiveDocument` loose their reference to their VBA-code within your template.

Unfortunately you can not simply hide command buttons, but you may disable them and set their size to 1x1 points:

```
With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)
    .OLEFormat.Object.Enabled = False
    .Width = 1
    .Height = 1
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for this workaround! It's not ideal, but it seems to be the only way of "hiding" some of the objects that are no longer useful in order to declutter a document.